# Get specific id from a listview

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` which is implemented using a customs adapter. For making the adapter i am using a `holder class`. The class has various `TextViews` and `ImageViews` as well as an Int variable id to store the id being fetched from the database. Now when i click the particular list i want to get the id so that using it I can further display the information on a new activity. The id is not meant to be displayed in the `ListView`. How can i get the id from `onItemClickListener()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a tag to a `View` (`.setTag()`) and then retrieve it, it happens on `getView()` method inside your custom `Adapter`

Here is a sample code:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {
        String transactionId = ((TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.tvTID)).getText().toString();
        handler.getTransactionDetails(callback, transactionId);
    }
});
```

Comment: the transactionID is not stored in any `TextView`. It is just stored as an integer variable as a member of holder class. So basically i cannot use `findViewById`

Comment: @AbhishekBatra As i mentioned, you need to set tag to a `View`. In this case the `transactionID` is set to my `TextView` as a tag (it won't show anywhere)

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {


    YourObject selected = adapter.getItem(position);
```

Then you can send the selected list item (Object) to your new activity

```
Intent mIntent = new Intent(ThisActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
        mIntent.putExtra("list_selected", selected);
        startActivity(mIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

> as well as an Int variable id to store the id being fetched from the
>   database.

You didn't provide more infomation about that **id** (i don't know exactly what it presents) but to make it simple you can set this id for each widget in `ListAdapter` via [setTag()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) method and then simply retrieve it from your `onItemClick()` method.